# How to convey the user that some of the form fields cannot be changed later?

Tags: forms, user-expectation, input-fields, wizard, ux-writing

I have a form wizard some input fields. On the first step of the wizard, there are 2 checkboxes which once the form has been submitted, cannot be edited. All other fields can be edited later on if the user wants to.

How do I tell the user that the two checkboxes cannot be edited so that they do not miss out on the message? Is the following message understandable?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Treat this like any other destructive/permeant act a user could take against data. Because this is an unchangeable option present a confirmation of choice.  This could be a secondary check box like agreeing to terms before submitting a payment, or a popup seeking a secondary yes.  Any text you put on the page no matter color will be skipped by some unless "forced" to read it.

Answer (score 1):

using red text-color makes it seem like a validation error. Would go for black.
Think of displaying it in parenthesis or move it below the checkbox.

Comment: This was my concern as well. However, I really do not want the user to miss out/ignore the text.

Answer (score 1):

How about focusing on the action the user can (or can't) take, instead of the form itself?

**This field is uneditable once saved**

becomes

**You can't change this once you save this form.**

- this gets rid of 'uneditable'
- what does 'field' mean to the user? If you can, this word should be specific to the information they're providing in the field.
- also, move from the passivity of 'once saved' to the more active 'once you save this form'

I realise you may be constrained by character count, etc., but I hope it helps!